# Edit event on click in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar

I was wondering if its possible to show a modal as you click an event in fullcalendar? Where the modal contains all the information of the event and you can edit it.
I do know how to show a modal when an event is selected but I can't figure out how do you pass the events id and append it to the modal.
I badly need your help, I'm still a newbie in web development so if you could show or explain how and what to do with this. :)

```
  eventclick: function(){
                $('#editevent').modal('show');

        },
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the [eventClick callback method](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/), and work with the first parameter, that is the event you have click.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
       //Here you can call your method to open your modal.
       //As I don't know your method, I will assume is called 'openModal', that receives an id as a parameter.
       openModal(event.id);
    }
});
```

Comment: sir I was wondering, should I open the modal first then pass the values to it and append the form or should I pass the id first, fetch the values then append the form with values with it?

Comment: That will depend on the structure of your app. In fact, I don't know if that modal is a bootstrap modal or it's one you created displaying a popup form or... But, anyway, that's probably out of the scope of this question, so maybe it's better if you open a new one asking about how to pass parameters to a modal/form :)